# How can I change the font size of an edge label in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize

I got a little automata tikzpicture but the more complex it got, the less readable it became. So I wanted to adjust the font size of the edge labels but I just can't figure out how to do that. Tried looking in the tikzpgf manual and also on here but I only find `scale` and `fontsize` for the nodes but not for the edge labels in the path commands.

For example I want to make the text in these two paths here smaller:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,backgrounds}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
\node  [state, initial] (Neutral)       {Neutral};   
\node[state]
    (UI Popup)
    [right=of Neutral]
    {Popped UI};

\node[state]
    (Sine)
    [above right=of UI Popup]
    [fill=gray]
    {\includegraphics[width=1.8cm]{sinecurve2}};

\node[state, circle split]
    (Digital_Off)
    [scale=0.75]
    [below right=of UI Popup]
    {Digital [Off] \nodepart{lower} \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{pin_off}};

\node[state, circle split]
    (Digital_On)
    [scale=0.75]
    [right=of Digital_Off]
    {Digital [On] \nodepart{lower} \includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{pin_on}};

    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[fit=(Digital_Off) (Digital_On), rectangle, rounded corners, draw=red, label=above:Digital state] (digital) {};
\end{scope}

\path[->] [line width=0.3mm]
            (Neutral)       edge [scale=0.2] node [above]      {Tap}                    (UI Popup)
            (UI Popup)      edge [bend left] node [above left]  {Tap and select analog} (Sine)
                            edge [bend right] node [below left] {Tap and select digital}    (Digital_Off)
            (Digital_Off)   edge [bend left] node [above]      {Tap}                    (Digital_On)
            (Digital_On)    edge [bend left] node [below]      {Tap}                    (Digital_Off)
            %(digital)      edge [bend left] node [above]      {Tap}                    (Sine)    
            (digital)       edge [bend right] node [above]     {Long click}             (UI Popup)
            (Sine)          edge [bend left]  node [below]     {Long click}             (UI Popup)
                        ;                    
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Input pin behavior}
\end{figure}
```

**Edit:**

This tikzpicture is in a separate file which begins with \chapter{...} and the main.tex file looks like this:

```
%!TEX root = ./main.tex

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage]{book}
\include{i10preamble}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
\include{indexAddOn}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{
\put(0,0){
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{titlepage_Master_CID}}}
\strut
\end{titlepage}

% Lots of other stuff inside

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you add an MWE?

Comment: please show an example of your image in form of small but complete document. you can define edge node style with desired font size.  or can use `quotes` syntax for edge labels and define font size for quotes.

Comment: image is welcome, but we like to see your code for it :-)

Comment: preamble of your document with to image related packages and used libraries are important too ...

Comment: by the way, your code has (many) errors. please check it again, and please provide preamble related to this image. discovering which libraries you use is not fun.

Comment: @Zarko sorry I forgot they are relevant as well, will edit it now

Comment: The code must start with `\documentclass`  and end with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

meanwhile i wait on your complete mwe, i test your image code in my `tikz` testbed, consequently my preamble can differ from what you use in your document ...

i would write code for your image on the following way:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.multipart
                }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\greencirc{\tikz\node[circle, draw, thick, fill=green,
                                 minimum size=3ex, node contents={}];}
\newcommand\whitecirc{\tikz\node[circle, draw, thick, fill=white,
                                 minimum size=3ex, node contents={}];}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
    MP/.style = {circle split, draw, inner sep=1pt,
                 align=center, font=\scriptsize},
state/.append style = {fill=#1, align=center},
state/.default = white,
every edge quotes/.append style={font=\scriptsize, align=center, auto}% style for edge labels
    ]
\node (Neutral)     [state, initial]            {Neutral};
\node (UI Popup)    [state, right=of Neutral]   {Popped\\ UI};
\node (Sine)        [state=gray!50, above right=of UI Popup]
    {sinecurve2};%{sinecurve2}};
\node (Digital Off) [MP, below right=of UI Popup]
        {Digital\\ {[Off]} \nodepart{lower} \\ \whitecirc};

\node (Digital On) [MP, right=of Digital Off]
        {Digital\\ {[On]} \nodepart{lower} \\  \greencirc};

%\scoped[on background layer]
\node  (digital) [rounded corners, draw=red, label=75:Digital state,
                  fit=(Digital Off) (Digital On)] {};
\path[thick, ->]
    (Neutral)       edge ["Tap"]                                    (UI Popup)
    (UI Popup)      edge [bend  left,"Tap and\\ select analog"]     (Sine)
                    edge [bend right,"Tap and\\ select digital" ']  (Digital Off)
    (Digital Off)   edge [bend left,"Tap" ']                        (Digital On)
    (Digital On)    edge [bend left,"Tap" ']                        (Digital Off)
    (digital)       edge [bend right, "Long\\ click" ']               (UI Popup)
    (Sine)          edge [bend left, "Long\\ click" ']                (UI Popup)
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

as you see, all fonts size are defined in nodes/edge quotes styles. also are replaced two images with new commands `greencirc` and `whitecirc`. similarly can be done for sine way in grayed node.

[image]

Comment: This looks way better than what I had, thank you! I am quite new to tikz and pgf and don't understand the styling (starting with `MP/.style = ...` yet but will look into it. Do you have any helpful links aside from the tikz manual which can help me get into that?

Comment: And also, why does `'` change the position of the edge label? Or rather, where can I read into that, is that due to the quotes parameter?

Comment: `'` is shortcut for `swap`, see *17.8 Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly*, page 236 (tikz & opgf manual, v 3.0.2.a.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `scale` DOES work, but I just tried it at the wrong part in the parameters.

What I tried was

```
    (UI Popup)      edge [scale=0.5] [bend left] node [above left]  {Tap and select analog} (Sine)
```

But correct would be

```
    (UI Popup)      edge [bend left] node [scale=0.5] [above left]  {Tap and select analog} (Sine)
```